# Is there a way to leverage a custom inertial model for the robot_localization state estimation EKF?

Tags: ros2, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node, ekf-localization

I have a model I evaluated that better models the state of the system my EKF is tracking than the out-of-the-box model provided by robot_localization. Is there a way to just swap out the inertial model provided?

Answer (score 0):

The package wasn't really designed for that. However, you can create your own package and inherit from the base classes in the package to implement your models.

A better option would be to just use [fuse](https://github.com/locusrobotics/fuse), which is meant to be the "spritual successor" to r_l, but improved in literally every way. It has first-class support for implementing your own models.